# Need static port to work with app in netlify production build

Tags: reactjs, netlify

Is there any way to change port in netlify actually need static port 3000 to make my app work.

The App need port 3000 in netlify prod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Netlify CLI](https://cli.netlify.com/) and pass in the command:

```
netlify dev -p 3000
```

Specifying custom ports for Netlify Dev:

- **targetPort**: The port for your application server, framework or site generator.
- **port**: The port for the Netlify Dev server, the one you'll open in the browser.

[ref](https://cli.netlify.com/netlify-dev/#explanation-of-ports-in-netlify-dev)

Answer (score 0):

Use this when running server

```
netlify dev -p (your port e.g: 8885)
```